# what is wrong with this php code

Tags: php, php-5.3

It is spitting the synatx error with this part of cdoe.can you please tell me what is wrong with this code

```
class House{
    private $color;

    public function paint($color){
        $ret_col = create_function("\$color", "Painting with the color \$color");
        return $ret_col;    
    } 
}

$hs = new House();
$col = $hs->paint('red');
echo $col;
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in test.php(37) runtime-created function on line 1

Comment: `Painting with the color $color` is not valid PHP  syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Function body is not valid Php code.

Maybe you should write it

```
class House{
    private $color;

    public function paint($color){
        $ret_col = create_function("\$color", "return \"Painting with the color \$color\";");
        return $ret_col;    
    } 
}

$hs = new House();
$col = $hs->paint('red');
echo $col();
```

Edit: Fixed the col error Rocket pointed out.

And also the closure example Kendal Hopkins has is actually an nicer way for php 5.3+.

Comment: @david:When i use the  same code it is outputting me as "lambda_2" where iam expecting "painting with color red"

Comment: `$col` is a function, so you need to `echo $col()`.

Comment: While this is "correct", it's not really good practice to use `create_function` in PHP 5.3.

Comment: @Kendall, I just added that  :D, your way is better but I have not worked with the new feature yet, to much old code to keep running.

Comment: @David: even we need to pass the value for the col() it is something like this echo col('Brown')

Comment: AH, missed that one. But a down wote, my answer might not be complete but the parts I fixed was correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you using PHP 5.3 don't use `create_function`. Instead use PHP's [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). They allow for the internal code to be checked when the file is read instead of when it's executed and is often safer. Also, you must execute the closure in order to get the value from it, you can't simply typecast it to a string.

```
class House{
    private $color;

    public function paint($color){
        $ret_col = function() use ($color) { //use a closure
            return "Painting with the color $color";
        };
        return $ret_col;    
    } 
}

$hs = new House();
$col = $hs->paint('red');
echo $col(); //not just $col
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) must be a valid PHP string.
You should do something like:

```
create_function("$color", 'return "Painting with the color" . $color;');
```

furthermore you have another error: when you do `return $ret_col;` you are returning the lambda function not the return value of the lambda function so you have to correct your code:

```
class House{
    private $color;

    public function paint($color){
        $ret_col = create_function("$color", 'return "Painting with the color" . $color;');
        return $ret_col;    
    } 
}

$hs = new House();
$col = $hs->paint('red');
echo $col();
```

Notice the bracket after `echo $col`

Comment: even we need to pass the value for the col() it is something like this echo col('yellow')

Comment: But as @Kendall Hopkins said, if you are using PHP 5.3 use closures, less pain more easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

you can't execute

```
 Painting with the color $color
```

but you can

```
 $ret_col = create_function('$color', 'return "Painting with the color ".$color;');
```